# Can I replace two 2x4 jack studs with a steel bracket attached to side of adjacent 6x6 king stud?

Tags: walls, framing, structural, studs, removal

As part of my kitchen remodel, I want to move my refrigerator into a closet.  In order for the refrigerator to fit width-wise, I need to remove two jack studs on one side of the closet that are supporting a double 2x12 header which is a bearing wall for the ceiling joists and second floor bedroom.

The header butts up against a 6x6 king stud that the jack studs are nailed to.

My question is:

- Can I fabricate a steel bracket lag-bolted to the side of the king stud to support the header instead of the studs?
- Would I need to extend such a bracket down the side of the 6x6 and attach it to a steel plate at the foot so the weight remains supported on the floor rather than hanging on the side?
- How thick should steel plate be?

(*Note in the pictures there is a third stud which I removed, shown in the location where I pulled it from. The bracket would replace this stud as well*)

**View from inside closet**
[image]

**View from outside closet (bracket would be on the left hand side)**
*Removing the studs frees up the three-inch space to the right of the 6x6 post*
[image]

**Bracket Idea**
[image]

Comment: What is the header supporting and what is the 6x6 supporting?

Comment: It’s difficult to recommend a homemade bracket. If the load on the header was known, then a manufacturered bracket could be recommended.

Comment: Can a bracket be made for this? Sure. Can you do it with some back-of-the-envelope calculations? If you had the engineering chops for that, you wouldn't be asking here. You know that this is a load-bearing wall, we can only recommend that you contact a local structural engineer to have him design the proper accommodation for this. Without that, you risk serious damage to your house, potential injury to anyone in it, and risk having your insurance company not pay a claim since it's a home made fix and not signed off.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this needs a Structural Engineer to make a safe assessment of what is necessary to prevent collapse of the OP's second floor.

Comment: What sits on the header?

Comment: This picture (https://postimg.cc/dLCn7SM5) hopefully shows the full context, with blue arrows pointing to the header and supporting studs I want to replace.  The full header runs parallel to the roofline and includes the wall between two downstairs bedrooms, hallway, closet as shown, and basement steps.  The master bedroom is above.  I concluded I will not attempt to do this myself.  However it seems that a properly fabricated steel bracket should be able to do this job.  Has anyone seen a similar situation and how the problem was resolved?